# Can you change the color of the titlebar of a userform in VBA using Windows API?

Tags: vba, winapi, excel, titlebar

Is it possible to change the color of the title bar for a VBA userform using Windows API. Please note that I am only interested in changing the color of the title bar for a particular userform and not a system-wide them change. Thanks!

Comment: what would you need to do that for? :O It's possible but now you're asking for code, aren't you?

Comment: Good question! It is purely for aesthetic reason :) I have a userform with a "green theme" (Green text, green logo etc..), my colleague thinks that the blue title bar looks ugly, so I was wondering if I change the color of the title bar to something more green

Comment: it's not very easy...I have found [**this**](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/change-color-title-bar-user-form-t2748773.html) but haven't tested it

Comment: Aero does not allow per-window tinting so its unlikely there is a way to do it.  You can remove the title bar entirely with the API, add an image/coloured shape and use the mouse capture API to allow dragging. (You would lose the outer Aero border as well)

Comment: just a note: consider making a Windows Forms or WPF application if you want to be able to customize a lot of UI. Excel's Userform is pretty basic and very restricted in terms of modification - it has some basic properties etc but once it gets to modifying anything with WinAPI I would make a switch to onto a WPF even if I had to rewrite everything to C#. If it's just an aesthetic reason then you need to decide yourself if it's worth the hassle but @AlexK.'s above solution seems pretty reasonable and not too difficult to implement so maybe have a go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for fun;

[image]

**UserForm:**

```
Private gHWND As Long

Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If Button = 1 Then HandleDragMove gHWND
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    gHWND = Setup(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

***.BAS**

```
Option Explicit
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = &HA1&
Private Const HTCAPTION = 2&
Private Const GWL_STYLE = (-16)
Private Const WS_BORDER = &H800000
Private Const WS_DLGFRAME = &H400000
Private Const WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER Or WS_DLGFRAME
Private Declare Sub ReleaseCapture Lib "User32" ()
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "User32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal HWND As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal HWND As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "User32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal HWND As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Function Setup(objForm As Object) As Long
    Setup = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", objForm.Caption)
    SetWindowLong Setup, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(Setup, GWL_STYLE) And Not WS_CAPTION
End Function

Public Sub HandleDragMove(HWND As Long)
    Call ReleaseCapture
    Call SendMessage(HWND, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0&)
End Sub
```

(Would need mod for 64bit Office)

Comment: Well, color me impressed!

Comment: Alex, I don't know what's the difference with VBA's Module and that /*.BAS/ of Windows API (I'm not so experienced) but I tried the same thing on my `VBA User Form` but it doesn't work. Firstly it doesn't recognize `gHWND` variable, I don't know why. (I defined it as `Dim gHWND as Long` before `gHWND = Setup(Me)` ) And I write that `*.BAS` part of your code into my `Module8` But then the only thing happens on my *userform* when I run it is, instead of changing the color, **Title Bar Disappears** Why it's acting like this? How can I run it correctly? That seems wonderful by the way, cheers.

Comment: I should also mention that, I have another *User Form* as a `Splash Screen` of my workbook. And in that splash screen I have a `Public Sub HideTitleBar` macro but it's in different Module and I don't think they have any duplicate variable so that your macro confusing with it and running that one instead of your one.

Comment: Sorry for consecutive comments Alex, but I think I now understood what you have done! You are not `changing the title`, but you are only `hiding title bar`, then the green thing we see as a title is `a green fancy picture` located at the top of user form, and `Green Machine Label` over that picture. Picture also has a `Special Effect 6- (Bump)` to show it like Title :)  wow that's smart way actually.

Comment: Yep, the green stuff at the top is an image in an image control, the white text is a label control who's mousemove event is used to allow dragging.