# How to change the color of form in title bar in ax 2012 R3

Tags: axapta

I want to change the color of the Title bar/Action pane in a form but it should be applicable to all default forms in the application.

I tried with run method in SysSetupFormRun class.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the .xpo provided in this thread:
It changes the footer not the title bar but it may work for your issue.

http://www.agermark.com/2011/12/color-code-forms-in-ax-2012-depending.html

BR,
Kristian

Comment: Thanks Kristian, this thing i tried but i want to change the title bar color.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ready code for you could expand the WinAPI class and do some WinAPI calls to set the title bar color.

I believe you would need the `SetWindowLong` function from `user32.dll`.

Have a look at `WinAPI.appendMenu()` for an example on how to call into `user32.dll`

You should probably be able to convert the code from this post: [Can you change the color of the titlebar of a userform in VBA using Windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634056/can-you-change-the-color-of-the-titlebar-of-a-userform-in-vba-using-windows-api)

Then you should hook it into the SysSetupFormRun or FormRun class as you tried.

Comment: Tom V, what need to  do changes in WinAPI class and SetWindowLong ,i did not understand what you told top

Comment: Answer updated, look into WinAPI.appendmenu() to see how to add a method from user32.dll

Comment: Tom V,Please tell me in detail what need to change in appendmenu() and   SetWindowLong ().

Comment: You need to implement setwindowlong (i think, haven't tested) just like appendmenu is implemented

Comment: Do  you call it like the linked post? Just adding the method will not do anything if you don't call it.

Comment: Already default setwindowlong () method is implemented.where to call this method

Comment: in the formrun active for example